# Lua:  __lt metamethod setting is not working how I want 

Tags: lua

This is my first quesion to this incredible community.

In these days I'm writing a Lua module for myself. Here it is a minimum part of the code with the problem

```
mt = {}

bf = {}

------------
-- bf.new --
------------
function bf.new(A)

    local out = A
    setmetatable(out,mt)
    return out

end

-----------------
-- bf.tostring --
-----------------
function bf.tostring(A)

    local typeA = type(A)
    local out   = ""
    if typeA=="number" or typeA=="boolean" then
        print(tostring(A))
    elseif typeA=="table" then
        local col    = ""
        local m      = #A
        local typeA1 = type(A[1])
        for i=1,m do
            if typeA1=="table" then
                n = #A[1]
                for j=1,n do
                    out = out.." "..tostring(A[i][j])
                    if j==n then
                        out = out.."\n"
                    end
                end
            elseif (typeA1=="number" or typeA1=="boolean") then
                row = row.." "..tostring(A[i][j])
            end
        end
    end
    return out
end

-----------------------------
-- bf.compare(A,logical,B) --
-----------------------------
function bf.compare(A,logical,B)

    if (logical~="<"  and
        logical~=">"  and
        logical~="<=" and
        logical~=">=" and
        logical~="==" and
        logical~="~=") then
        error("second input input must be a logical operator written into a string")
    end
    local out   = {}
    local ind   = {}
    local count = 0
    if type(B)=="number" then
        if type(A[1])=="table" then
            for i=1,#A do
                out[i] = {}
                for j=1,#A[1] do
                    loadstring("cond ="..A[i][j]..logical..B)()
                    if cond then
                        out[i][j]  = true
                        count      = count+1
                        ind[count] = (i-1)*#A[1]+j
                    else
                        out[i][j]  = false
                    end
                end
            end
        elseif type(A[1])=="number" then
            for j=1,#A do
                loadstring("cond ="..A[j]..logical..B)()
                if cond then
                    out[j]     = true
                    count      = count+1
                    ind[count] = j
                else
                    out[j]     = false
                end
            end
        end
    else
        if (type(A[1])=="table" and type(B[1])=="table") then
            if (#A==#B and #A[1]==#B[1]) then
                for i=1,#A do
                    out[i] = {}
                    for j=1,#A[1] do
                        loadstring("cond ="..A[i][j]..logical..B[i][j])()
                        if cond then
                            out[i][j]  = true
                            count      = count+1
                            ind[count] = (i-1)*#A[1]+j
                        else
                            out[i][j] = false
                        end
                    end
                end
            else
                error("The comparison can be done between "..
                      "two matrix with same dimension "..
                      "or between a matrix with a scalar value")
            end
        elseif (type(A[1])=="number" and type(B[1])=="number") then
            if (#A==#B) then
                for j=1,#A do
                    loadstring("cond ="..A[j]..logical..B[j])()
                    if cond then
                        out[j] = true
                        count      = count+1
                        ind[count] = j
                    else
                        out[j] = false
                    end
                end
            else
                error("Comparison between "..
                      "two vector with different dimension")
            end
        else
            error("The comparison can be done between "..
                  "two matrix with same dimension "..
                  "or between a matrix with a scalar value")
        end
    end
    return setmetatable(out,mt)--,ind

end

------------------------
-- metamethod setting --
------------------------
mt.__tostring = bf.tostring
mt.__lt       = function(A,B) return bf.compare(A,"<",B) end

--------------------------
-- use of my metamethod --
--------------------------
A  = bf.new{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}
B  = bf.new{{3,6,1,8},{1,3,87,20},{11,2,5,7}}
C1 = bf.compare(A,"<",B)
C2 = A<B
print("What I want")
print(C1)
print("What I get")
print(C2)
```

If you run this little script, you can see that when I use the function bf.compare directly I have what I need. When I use the bf.compare through the metamethod, it gives me only a "scalar" value of true.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**

Here it is the output:

```
What I want
 true true false true
 false false true true
 true false false false

What I get
true
>Exit code: 0
```

Comment: I can't really see that at all, because you don't show the output.

Comment: +1 for actually giving working code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4) states this pseudo code for the `__lt metamethod`:

```
function lt_event (op1, op2)
       if type(op1) == "number" and type(op2) == "number" then
         return op1 < op2   -- numeric comparison
       elseif type(op1) == "string" and type(op2) == "string" then
         return op1 < op2   -- lexicographic comparison
       else
         local h = getbinhandler(op1, op2, "__lt")
         if h then
           return not not h(op1, op2)
         else
           error(···)
         end
       end
     end
```

if there is a metamethod, then this line `return not not h(op1, op2)` returns only a singel (the first) value returned by the handler `h`, as `not` is a unary operator. As a second effect it converts the handler output to a scalar: `not {} == false`, and `not false == true`.

Another small thing to notice: Lua tables are always passed by reference. Assigning a table to another variable just results in copying the pointer. Hence if you do stuff like:

```
function myFun(A)
    local out=A
    out[1]='bar'
    return out
end
A={'foo',1,2,3}
B=myFun(A)
print(table.concat(B,', ')) -- OK
print(table.concat(A,', ')) -- A also changed, because:
print(A,B) -- they are the same table!
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of all comparison metamethods is automatically cast to a boolean.